# Rails 5 Custom module function not found in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app and custom module stored at `lib/reusable.rb`.

```
module Reusable

    def createCharge(amount, source, description, customer)

        charge_params = {
            amount: amount,
            source: source,
            description: description,
            currency: 'usd'
        }

        return charge_params
    end
end
```

I've added the following to `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

When I start the console, I can run the following:

```
2.3.4 :002 > include Reusable
 => Object
2.3.4 :003 > x = Reusable.createCharge(100, 1, "ffwefwef")
{
         :amount => 100,
         :source => 1,
    :description => "ffwefwef",
       :currency => "usd"
}
```

But in my controller I cannot do the same.  When I try the following:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
    before_action :set_client, only: [:new, :create]
    before_action :set_order, only: [:create]

    include Reusable

    def create
        charge_attempt = Reusable.createCharge(total, token, description, customer)
    end
end
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `createCharge' for Reusable:Module):
```

Any ideas why it's not finding the function?  I've restarted my app and printed `Reusable.methods` to my console and the function is not there.

Comment: Looks like you are both mixing in `Reusable` to your class, and calling the method directly. Generally speaking, you only need to do one or the other. If you mix it in, then you can call it directly, without `Reusable.`: `charge_attempt = createCharge(total, token, description, customer)`. If you want to call it directly, then it needs to be defined as a singleton method on `Reusable`. `module_function` can do this for you, and then you can use it both ways if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to make your `createCharge` method available...

One way is `module_function`...

```
module Reusable
  def create_charge(amount, source, description, customer)
    charge_params = {
      amount: amount,
      source: source,
      description: description,
      currency: 'usd'
    }
    charge_params
  end

  module_function :create_charge
end
```

Another approach is to use self...

```
def self.create_charge(amount, source, description, customer)
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `module_function` over `def self.`?

Comment: Actually, there is a subtle difference that comes into play when you include the module: it is copied as a private instance method. So [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function) is slightly more flexible in how it can be used. See also [`module_function` vs `extend self`](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/8-self-improvement.html)